# Transient Heatflow in a Wheel Disc Brake

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I try to model the Convection–diffusion equation for a rotating 3D annulus(small thickness):

[image]

The temperature `u[t,x,y,z]` is described in cartesian coordinates.

**parameters**

```
t1 = 2;
r1 = .161;r2 = .201;d = 0.02;\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi] = 20. Degree;
\[Rho]c = 2.419*^6;\[Lambda] = 172.;
p = 1.855 10^7;\[Alpha] = 90.;\[Omega] = 110.;T0 = 50;
```

The heat flux `p` (constant for reasons of simplification) is applied in a local range of the disc. Convection `\[Alpha]` is considered at the side `z==d/2`.

**meshing**

Because thickness is much smaller than the radii the automatic meshing leads to
huge element meshes(NDSolve can't start:::) I predefine a simple mesh (using [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package package, thanks to @pinti))

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["MeshTools`"]

mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {    r1 ,  r2 }, {0, 2 Pi}, {36, 10}];
mesh = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, d/2, 5];
scheibe = HexToTetrahedronMesh[mesh]
```

[image]

**simulation**

The system is simulated with `MethodOfLines` and `FiniteElement` because  these methods allow the description of flux-boundaries using  `NeumannValue`.

```
U = Monitor[
NDSolveValue[{ \[Rho]c ( Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][u][t, x, y,z] + \[Omega] {-y, x, 0}.Grad[ u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}]) ==   \[Lambda]  Laplacian[u[t, x, y, z] , {x, y, z}] 
+ p NeumannValue[1, -x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2] <= y <= x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2] &&  z ==  d/2]
- \[Alpha]    NeumannValue[(u[t, x, y, z] - 0),z ==  d/2 && ! (-x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2] <= y <= x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2])   ]
, u[0, x, y, z] == T0},
u,{t, 0, t1}, Element[{x, y, z}, scheibe] 
, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement" }}, EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor= Row[{"t = ", CForm[Round[t, .01]]}])] , monitor]
```

Results of simulation

```
Show[{SliceDensityPlot3D[U[t, x, y, d/2], {"XStackedPlanes", Subdivide[0,t1, 5]},  {t, 0,t1}, {x, -r2, r2}, {y, -r2, r2},PlotRange -> {0, All},RegionFunction -> Function[{t, x, y}, r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2],AxesLabel -> {Zeit,None,None}, Ticks -> {Automatic, None, None},ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &), PlotLegends ->BarLegend[{(ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &), {0, 200}}]]}]
```

[image]

seem to be ok, but `NDSolve` gives a warning

`NDSolveValue::femcsp: The computed Peclet number is 515.3080637051237` and is larger than the mesh order (1), and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.`

Checking temperature over time (smooth curve expected)

```
Plot[U[t, 0, (r1 + r2)/2, d/2], {t, 0, t1},AxesLabel -> {time, temperature}]
```

[image]

indicates numerical problems.

**My questions**

How to avoid message `peclet-number`? Using automated meshgeneration inside NDSolve leads to huge mesh( NDSolve doesn't run)

How to force smooth time response?

Thanks!

Comment: @user21 Thanks for editing my question. I'm curious about your thoughts about this problem.

Comment: I had a brief look but could not come up with something. I'll hope to find some time to put it on a big machine to see if that would actually solve the issue. But might take some time until I get to that.

Comment: @user21 Thanks, I'll await your contribution!

Comment: Should these not overlap? `Show[Region[
  ImplicitRegion[-x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2] <= y <= 
    x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2], {x, y}]], 
 Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, r2], Disk[{0, 0}, r1]]]]`

Comment: @user21 Yes the regions must be the same. Change the first to `Region[ImplicitRegion[-x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2] <= y <=x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2] && r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2, {x, y}]]`

Comment: Don't *you* need to change that in your equation setup; otherwise your boundary condition will not be applied? In other words: It looks to me as if your first NeumannValue does not really intersect the boundary, or does it?

Comment: @user I hope it does, because I restrict the parameter-range to "scheibe" which  includes the second restriction `r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2`

Comment: For future reference, there is a [Disc Brake](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/ModelCollection/DiskBrake.html) application example.

Comment: @user21 Thank you, very interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can add artificial viscosity to correct the imperfections of the mesh. But for this problem, the artificial viscosity is 632 times greater than $\lambda$. The second option is to change the model - go to the reference system where the disk is stationary and the heat source is moving. In this case, there are also messages regarding the calculation of a compiled function. But this does not spoil the numerical solution.

```
t1 = 2;
r1 = .161; r2 = .201; d = 0.02; \[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi] = 
 20. Pi/180;
\[Rho]c = 2.419*^6; \[Lambda] = 172.;
p = 1.855 10^7; \[Alpha] = 90.; \[Omega] = 110.; T0 = 50.;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["MeshTools`"]

mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {r1, r2}, {0, 2 Pi}, {36, 10}];
mesh = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, d/2, 5];
scheibe = HexToTetrahedronMesh[mesh]

U = NDSolveValue[{\[Rho]c Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][u][t, x, y, 
       z] == \[Lambda] Laplacian[u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 
      p NeumannValue[
        1, -x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2 - \[Omega] t] <= y <= 
          x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2 - \[Omega] t] && 
         z == d/2] -  \[Alpha] NeumannValue[(u[t, x, y, z] - 0.), 
        z == d/2 && ! (-x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/
                2 - \[Omega] t] <= y <= 
            x Tan[\[CapitalDelta]\[CurlyPhi]/2 - \[Omega] t])], 
    u[0, x, y, z] == T0}, u, {t, 0, t1}, Element[{x, y, z}, scheibe], 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}] // Quiet
```

The result is different from what it was in the original version, but the solution here is smooth.

```
Show[{SliceDensityPlot3D[
   U[t, x, y, d/2], {"XStackedPlanes", Subdivide[0, t1, 5]}, {t, 0, 
    t1}, {x, -r2, r2}, {y, -r2, r2}, PlotRange -> {0, All}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{t, x, y}, r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2], 
   AxesLabel -> {Zeit, None, None}, Ticks -> {Automatic, None, None}, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &), 
   PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[{(ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &), {0, 2000}}]]}]

Plot[U[t, 0, (r1 + r2)/2, d/2], {t, 0, t1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {time, temperature}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

It is necessary to normalize `p` and $\alpha$ to the real area. Then the scales coincide with Ulrich Neumann result.

```
p = 1.855 10^7 20/360; \[Alpha] = 90.*340/360;
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101655/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-trounev-transient-heatflow-in-a-wheel-disc-brake).